# Is INotifyDataErrorInfo broken for WPF 4.5 DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have made a simple implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo in a WPF 4.5 project.  This is a new interface for WPF but has been available in Silverlight for some time.

I know that NET4.5 is still considered alpha but I'm trying to work out if it is my code or the framework at fault.

The interface works as expected but fails when an object is bound to a DataGrid.

The exception I receive is:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=PresentationFramework   StackTrace:
>          at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnDataErrorsChanged(INotifyDataErrorInfo
>   indei, String propName)
>          at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnErrorsChanged(Object sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
>          at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
>          at System.ComponentModel.ErrorsChangedEventManager.OnErrorsChanged(Object
>   sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs args)
>          at INotifyDataErrorInfoTest.Person.NotifyErrorsChanged(String property) in INotifyDataErrorInfoTest\Person.cs:line 109
>          at INotifyDataErrorInfoTest.Person.AddErrorForProperty(String property, String error) in INotifyDataErrorInfoTest\Person.cs:line 122
>          at INotifyDataErrorInfoTest.Person.Validate(String propertyName) in INotifyDataErrorInfoTest\Person.cs:line 150
>          at INotifyDataErrorInfoTest.Person.set_FirstName(String value) in INotifyDataErrorInfoTest\Person.cs:line 18

The code is below or in project at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14740106/INotifyDataErrorInfoTest.zip

If consensus is that this is a bug then I will post to MS Connect.

Testing:
There are two textboxes bound to a single instance of a Person object.  Set the first textbox to have a value of James and it will fail validation and show the red box.  If you set the first name of any user in the grid to James the exception will be thrown.

PS: I know it is not MVVM but it is just to prove or disprove the problem.

```
 public class Person : INotifyDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                Validate("FirstName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }

        string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                Validate("LastName");
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        public Person()
        {
        }

        public Person(string first, string last)
        {
            this._firstName = first;
            this._lastName = last;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Event to indicate that a property has changed.
        /// </summary>
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when a property is changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed.</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when a property is changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">PropertyChangedEventArgs</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Validate the property
            Validate(e.PropertyName);

            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }

        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyDataErrorInfo Members

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                return (_errors.Values);
            }

            MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(propertyName);
            return _errors[propertyName];
        }

        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get
            {
                return (_errors.Where(c => c.Value.Count > 0).Count() > 0);
            }
        }

        void NotifyErrorsChanged(string property)
        {
            if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            {
                ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
        public void ClearErrorFromProperty(string property)
        {
            MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(property);
            _errors[property].Clear();
            NotifyErrorsChanged(property);
        }
        public void AddErrorForProperty(string property, string error)
        {
            MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(property);
            _errors[property].Add(error);
            NotifyErrorsChanged(property);
        }

        void MakeOrCreatePropertyErrorList(string propertyName)
        {
            if (!_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                _errors[propertyName] = new List<string>();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Force the object to validate itself using the assigned business rules.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property to validate.</param>
        public void Validate(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (propertyName == "FirstName")
            {
                if (FirstName == "James")
                {
                    AddErrorForProperty(propertyName, "FirstName can't be James");
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearErrorFromProperty(propertyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public class NameList : ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        public NameList()
            : base()
        {
            Add(new Person("Willa", "Cather"));
            Add(new Person("Isak", "Dinesen"));
            Add(new Person("Victor", "Hugo"));
            Add(new Person("Jules", "Verne"));
        }
    }

   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Person _person = new Person();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public Person Person
        {
            get { return _person; }
        }
}

<Window x:Class="INotifyDataErrorInfoTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:INotifyDataErrorInfoTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <c:NameList x:Key="NameListData"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
        <TextBlock>To generate an error, set the FirstName of any row to James.
        </TextBlock>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NameListData}}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is YES.  I opened a [ticket with Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/696678/is-inotifydataerrorinfo-broken-for-wpf-4-5-datagrids) and they have confirmed that the code is fine and it is a bug with the .NET 4.5 DataGrid.

> This is our bug, not yours. When you edit a DataGrid cell, the DataGrid discards bindings for the "display" template and replaces them with bindings for the "edit" template. The discarded bindings should stop listening to the INDEI.ErrorsChanged event. They don't (that's the bug), but they are not prepared to get the event any more. When the event arrives, a null-reference crash occurs.
>
> This will be fixed in the final release. Thanks for finding and reporting it.

Pretty big bug to have to wait until the final release.  Let's hope it gets fixed by the next release.

Comment: you got a link to the bug so that I can track it?